# Formatting the value in the cell of a table

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I made a table and the corresponding SQLContainer. The table have a column with phone numbers. In db table type of the corresponding column is a int. I wish formatting values of Vaadin table, in such way that view phone numbers become without comas or dots like separator of thousand(8,888 -> 8888).

I have already made similar thing to the Table which data source is a JPAContainer on this way:

```
Table imenikTable = new Table("Imenik", imenikData){
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8213291207581835298L;

            @Override
            protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId,
                    Object colId, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Property property) {

                Object v =  property.getValue();

                if (v instanceof Integer) {

                DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(getLocale());
                df.applyLocalizedPattern("##00");
                return df.format(v);


                }
                return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
            }
        };
```

And everything works well. But when i made similar construction with SQLContiner instead of JPAContainer formatting is simply ignored. Affter that i try to change the way like this:

```
StringToIntegerConverter plainIntegerConverter = new StringToIntegerConverter(){

                private static final long serialVersionUID = -7517984934588222147L;

                protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale){
                    NumberFormat format = super.getFormat(locale);
                    format.setGroupingUsed(false);
                    return format;
                }
            };

            contaktListTable.setConverter("telbr", plainIntegerConverter);
```

But still my environment ignores me, even no error messages! What can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
Object v =  property.getValue();
```

is not returning an Integer value when you use the SQLContainer and that's why you are not seeing any exceptions, the conditional block is not being executed.

Can you check that with a break point?

Comment: Yes I checked. And I came to the same conclusion. I'm trying to do the conversion on the presentation level. In the MySql base is the int type. And what type can be in SQLcontainer before conversion in Table(where it become String)?

Comment: Are you using Oracle DB? The book of vaadin is telling this:                           When using Oracle database most or all of the numeric types are converted to
java.math.BigDecimal by the Oracle JDBC Driver.

Comment: Yes I check with break point. this value is not Integer. Because it is ignored break point. But when I looked at the type of value that contains the data column(during debugging) I have found it to type java.lang.Integer. I'm not skillful in debugging.It is possible that my observations in that regard is not reliable.

Comment: Not I use MySql! Thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: when you are adding the Phone property to the table, are you specifying it as an Integer? doing this imenikTable.addContainerProperty("Phone",Integer.class,null);   I did a quick test on my environment and is working in this way. I can share the code if needed but is really simple.